# Create a transmission through PCIE lines or Ethernet lines

Tags: usb, ethernet, usb-c, pcie

I'm working on a data transmission design.

I would like to create a data transmission from a Raspberry Compute Module 4, but I don't know what is the better way to do that. A USB-C is required, and the data transmission must be done by USB lines. Using a PCIE to USB controller should be support Dual Role Data to do that (supposing that create a transmission by PCIE lines were possible).

The other way I'm studying is using Ethernet to USB lines to create this transmission.

P.D: PCIE to USB controller is needed anyway.

[image]

[image]

Comment: So why not just buy an Ethernet to USB-C adapter?

Comment: what is the use case here? In the upper schema, the device attached to the USB C connector has to act as a **host** and control the USB network card – there's no "freestanding" USB network converters, these things simply aren't the same – and in the second, the attached device has to act as **device** (in the USB spec sense). Now, what do you need? Host and Device are pretty different as the host controls when what happens. If one is really an option, then the other is not. But we don't know what your use case is, so we can't help you.

Comment: It looks like a school assignment. Is it?

Comment: @MarcusMüller the use is only a unidireccional transmission to outside. I think with device feature should be ok, but by USB-C Controller like TPS65987 I can model the USB-C behaviour, right? The question is what is the easier way to create the transmission, by PCIE lines or by Ethernet?

Comment: again, this depends on what role the external device plays. Please explain your use case.

Comment: I want to send a data transmission from my device to other PC, external PC only receives the transmission.

Comment: @Ale..chenski no it isn't. It is a requirement of my design.